Python PyQt6 вопрос про Qt WebEngine открытие сайтов в новом окне
Помогите пожалуйста!
Есть проблема с которой не могу разобраться, а материалы в интернете ссылаются на определённое написание кода ручного, который я не писал, так как создавал интерфейс программы через Qt Designer.
Проблема в следующем: в программе есть несколько вкладок Tab и внутри каждой располагается Web страничка. Есть локальный сайт, сайт ЖКХ и они работают без проблем - если внутри них выбираю переход по ссылке, переход осуществляется в данном окне и в нём загружается новая страница на которую перехожу. Однако, есть страница с Google или Yandex (пробовал обе, не важно) и при поиске, когда получаю список сайтов - то не могу на них перейти. При клике на ссылку ничего не происходит. Картинки, новости могу глянуть, а вот на сайты перейти никак.
Внутри самого основного кода алгоритма программы к веб-движку относится только одна строка:
self.ui.webEmail.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl("https://www.yandex.ru/")) 

Остальное загружается из переработанного ui файла в py. Как мне заставить google например открывать ссылки внутри данного виджета? Я так понимаю, что проблема в том, что он пытается открыть в отдельном окне, а такой функции у меня в программе не реализовано.
Создание web-страницы сделано автоматическим кодом через Qt Designer

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Milk , пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать.
